# Setting Number Format to Accounting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
With ActiveSheet
.Range("T26:T31").NumberFormat = "_(£* #,##0.00_);_(£* (#,##0.00);_(£* " - "??_);_(@_)"
```

I am trying to set the format of a cell range to Accounting, I have looked at the number format (above) and tried setting it to that, but I get a Type Mismatch.

I also tried doing `Debug.Print Application.ActiveCell.NumberFormatLocal` to find out how excel reads it, copied that in and still with no luck.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double any quotation marks inside the format code, so:

```
.Range("T26:T31").NumberFormat = "_(£* #,##0.00_);_(£* (#,##0.00);_(£* "" - ""??_);_(@_)"
```